# React css formatting conditional on ant component

Tags: css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am trying to send in a style property to a component and not sure what the difference is..

Why does this statement work and applies the formatting

```
 <Toggle
className={styles.toggle_show}  // class name gets passed as Map_toggle_show__17ukO and applied 
/>
```

but this statement throws errors

```
 <Toggle
className={isShow ? {styles.toggle_show} : {styles.toggle_hide}}
/>
```

If I update the second statement to

```
 <Toggle
className={isShow ? "styles.toggle_show" : "styles.toggle_hide"}
/>
```

The classNames do get passed to the component but css dont get applied.

Also why is this message coming on the const declaration

```
import styles from "./Map.module.scss";

const [ToggleVisibilyClass, setToggleVisibilyClass] = React.useState(
    {styles.toggle_show}
  );

(property) styles: {
    readonly [key: string]: string;
}
Parsing error: ',' expected.eslint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
className={isShow ? styles.toggle_show : styles.toggle_hide}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way in your case will look like this:

```js
<Toggle
  className={isShow ? styles.toggle_show : styles.toggle_hide}
/>
```

`styles` is actually an object with string properties, so `{styles.toggle_show}` is not valid syntax, that's why you are getting an error.

And this `"styles.toggle_show"` is working because it's a string, but it's not the correct string. Behind the scenes Webpack generates a different name for your classes, usually a unique one and you can access it with `styles.toggle_show`.

Also if you have some more complicated scenarios try using the *classnames* package it can make things easier and it have a lot of examples.

Comment: Thanks so much Chavdar, that helped a bunch. Is that why I am getting this error (property) styles: {
    readonly [key: string]: string;
}
Parsing error: ',' expected.eslint

Comment: Actually {styles.toggle_show} was working and applying. too.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear on my end, i was referring to the `{styles.toggle_show} ` inside of `{isShow ? {styles.toggle_show} : {styles.toggle_hide}}`